# Suppress all warnings from my SPM package

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-warnings, swift-package-manager, snapshot-testing

Is there a way to suppress all warnings coming from my SPM Package in XCode?!

> ⚠️found 1 file(s) which are unhandled; explicitly declare them as
> resources or exclude from the target

This warning shows because my SPM package contains .txt file.

I tried adding `swiftSettings: [.unsafeFlags(["-suppress-warnings"])]` in **package.swift** but didn't work.

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.5
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Sourcery",
    platforms: [.macOS(.v10_13)],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
           url: "https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing.git",
           from: "1.9.0"
         )
    ],
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "Sourcery",
            dependencies: []
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SourceryTests",
            dependencies: [.product(name: "SnapshotTesting", package: "swift-snapshot-testing")]        
        )
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the exclude parameter supports folders as well. So I organized all .txt file in a folder and now I got rid of the warnings  :)

```swift
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "Sourcery",
    platforms: [.macOS(.v10_13)],
    dependencies: [
        .package(
           url: "https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-snapshot-testing.git",
           from: "1.9.0"
         )
    ],
    targets: [
        .executableTarget(
            name: "Sourcery",
            dependencies: [],
            exclude: ["Templates"]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SourceryTests",
            dependencies: [.product(name: "SnapshotTesting", package: "swift-snapshot-testing")],
            exclude: ["__Snapshots__"]
        )
    ]
)
```